# Xfinium page break if PdfFlowTableContent is wider that single page

Tags: c#, pdf, xamarin

I'm trying to generate a pdf document with a wide table on it and I want to break that table into several pages if the table doesn't fit a single page width.

How can I accomplish that in Xfinium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution at this moment is to create multiple tables, one table for a set of columns and add each table to the document.

For example if your table has 9 columns, create 3 tables with 3 columns and add them to the document. In this scenario all rows must have the same height otherwise the pages will not be balanced.